# Custom layout occupies all horizontal space

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom layout that lays views from left to right and if horizontal space runs out then it lays the next views below. If I put a basic text element that says "hello" inside this custom layout then the view occupies all the horizontal space. How can I adjust my setup so the custom layout only occupies the needed horizontal space?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomLayout {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
struct CustomLayout: Layout {
    var alignment: Alignment = .leading
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            if index == (rows.count - 1) {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
            } else {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
            }
        }
        
        return .init(width: maxWidth, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = bounds.origin
        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for row in rows {
            let leading: CGFloat = bounds.maxX - maxWidth
            let trailing = bounds.maxX - (row.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                
                if view == row.last {
                    return partialResult + width
                }
                return partialResult + width + spacing
            })
            let center = (trailing + leading) / 2
            
            origin.x = (alignment == .leading ? leading : alignment == .trailing ? trailing : center)
            
            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        
            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing)
        }
    }
    
    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin
        
        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            
            if (origin.x + viewSize.width + spacing) > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            } else {
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
            row.removeAll()
        }
        
        return rows
    }
}

extension [LayoutSubviews.Element] {
    func maxHeight(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGFloat {
        return self.compactMap { view in
            return view.sizeThatFits(proposal).height
        }.max() ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want this layout to do *in general*. It is easy to make it take up the ideal size of the view when there is only a single view, but the solution might remove other desirable features (which you have not stated) of this layout. So please clarify what this layout should do.

Comment: @Sweeper I just want this view to lay sub views from left to right. And it should lay as many sub views it can from left to right until the horizontal space runs out, at which point the next views go below.

Comment: How do you want the sizes of the subviews? Do you want the subviews to take up their ideal size (which means some views that would normally stretch to fill all the available space would not stretch), or do you want some other size proposal for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `sizeThatFits` needs to compute the width that it really needs to fit inside the proposal it receives. At the moment it is just returning the proposed width it is given, so it is always using the full available width.

For example, you could change the function `sizeThatFits` to something like this:

```swift
func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
    let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    var height: CGFloat = 0
    let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)

    for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
        var rowWidth = CGFloat.zero
        for (i, subview) in row.enumerated() {
            if i > 0 {
                rowWidth += spacing
            }
            rowWidth += subview.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
        }
        width = max(width, rowWidth)
        if index == (rows.count - 1) {
            height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
        } else {
            height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
        }
    }
    return .init(width: width, height: height)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]